# Facebook Audience network Interstitial ads crashes

Tags: android, facebook, interstitial

```
if (myApp.finterstitialAd3 == null) {
   myApp.finterstitialAd3 = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(this, getResources().getString(R.string.finterstitial3));
}
if (!myApp.finterstitialAd3.isAdLoaded()) {
    myApp.finterstitialAd3.loadAd();
}
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: InterstitialAd cannot be loaded while being displayed. Make sure your adapter calls adapterListener.onInterstitialDismissed().
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2678)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
>                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: InterstitialAd cannot be loaded while being displayed. Make sure your adapter calls adapterListener.onInterstitialDismissed().
>                                                                                               at com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd.loadAd(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd.loadAd(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at "------------------------".loadInterstitial(VideoDetail.java:121)
>                                                                                               at "-------".onCreate(VideoDetail.java:225)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6687)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with the com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd object. I was trying to call loadAd() on an interstitial that was already shown.
The solution for me was to destroy the old instance and create a new one, before loading the new ad:

```
if(interstitialAd != null)
    interstitialAd.destroy();
interstitialAd = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(context, id);
```

Also facebook have a new way for testing ads, so to make testing easy you can add "IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#" before the ad id(this will make sure your ad request is always filled for testing) and then remove it for the release version.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Interstitial Ads on Android Application

**Build.Gradle :**

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'
```

**MyAplication.java:**

```
AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<activity
     android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

**Permission:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**MainActivity :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private InterstitialAd facebookInterstitialAds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showFacebookInterstitial();
    }

    private void showFacebookInterstitial() {

        facebookInterstitialAds = new InterstitialAd(this, "Interstitial_Ad_ID");
        facebookInterstitialAds.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
                finish();
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
            }
        });
        facebookInterstitialAds.loadAd();
    }


    public void showAds(View view){

        if (facebookInterstitialAds.isAdLoaded())
            facebookInterstitialAds.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (facebookInterstitialAds != null)
            facebookInterstitialAds.destroy();
    }
}
```